# MySQL combine 2 rows into 1 with diffrent values

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have 2 tables and I want to combine these 2 tables into 1 (view) with 1 row per order. I want to check if an "id" from "order_address" table is linked with the "billing_address_id" from the "order" table. If thats the case this address is a billing-address and if its not linked is a shipping-address.

I tried a lot of things but I cant combine 2 rows with different values. See below. Is there some posibility to do this?

Order table:

| id | order_number | billing_address_id | order_date | order_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 147 | 2023-04-14 | 81.88 |
| 2 | 1002 | 369 | 2023-04-18 | 29.99 |

Order_address table:

| id | order_id | first_name | last_name | street | zipcode | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147 | 1 | John | Doe | Washington Street 2 | 33101 | Miami |
| 369 | 2 | Dave | Dunkin | Power Street 33a | 10010 | New York |
| 465 | 2 | Marry | Dunkin | Power Street 14 | 14205 | Buffalo |

Actual output:

| order_number | first_name | last_name | street | zipcode | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Peter | Paper | Washington Street 2 | 33101 | Miami |
| 1002 | John | Dunkin | Power Street 33a | 10010 | New York |
| 1002 | Marry | Dunkin | Other Street 14 | 14205 | Buffalo |

Wanted Output:

| order_number | first_name | last_name | street | zipcode | city | ship_first_name | ship_last_name | ship_street | ship_zipcode | ship_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Peter | Paper | Washington Street 2 | 33101 | Miami |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1002 | John | Dunkin | Power Street 33a | 10010 | New York | Marry | Dunkin | Other Street 14 | 14205 | Buffalo |

Comment: How do we distinguish between the first name and the ship first name?

Comment: If the "ID" from the "order_address" table is linked to the "billing_address_id" from the "order" table, it is a billing address, otherwise it is a shipping address. As mentioned in the start post ;)

Comment: order.billing_address_id = order_address.id => billing-address, 
order.billing_address_id != order_address.id => shipping-address

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to just have 1 column indicating shipping or billing?

Comment: Ofc it would be better but this is what the software serves you as the Database structure. So I need to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this view query. This will generate data as you expected.

```
CREATE VIEW order_with_addresses_vw AS 
SELECT 
    o.order_number, 
    b.first_name AS billing_first_name, 
    b.last_name AS billing_last_name, 
    b.street AS billing_street, 
    b.zipcode AS billing_zipcode, 
    b.city AS billing_city, 
    s.first_name AS shipping_first_name, 
    s.last_name AS shipping_last_name, 
    s.street AS shipping_street, 
    s.zipcode AS shipping_zipcode, 
    s.city AS shipping_city
FROM 
    orders o
LEFT JOIN 
    order_address b ON o.billing_address_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN 
    order_address s ON o.billing_address_id != s.id AND o.id = s.order_id;
```

Then you can run the select command for viewing the generated table.

```
SELECT * FROM order_with_addresses_vw ;
```

This is the output :

| order_number | billing_first_name | billing_last_name | billing_street | billing_zipcode | billing_city | shipping_first_name | shipping_last_name | shipping_street | shipping_zipcode | shipping_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John | Doe | Washington Street 2 | 33101 | Miami | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 1002 | Dave | Dunkin | Power Street 33a | 10010 | New York | Marry | Dunkin | Power Street 14 | 14205 | Buffalo |

Comment: Wow so quick and a clean query. This works perfect for me. The key here is the 2 left joins right? Could you explain a little bit, if not its cool. Thank you sir!